# Can I use my Views on a SQL Sever database in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ssms, sql-view, linked-tables

I have Views on a SQL server database that I have painstakingly written. I am creating linked tables on my MS Access Database. I am only able to pick from tables. Is there a way to use my Views on the SQL Server within MS Access, which has all the data I need?

Views in SSMS:

[image]

Can only see Tables in MS Access linked Tables manager:
[image]

Comment: You should be able to link a view just as you link a table. First, correct your two typos in the view name.

Comment: Gustav you pedant! Was actually the developers View (shown for example), mine are further down and spelled correctly.

Comment: But those I couldn't see ...

Comment: But I do agree, attention to detail is key in our line of work! It's just sloppy to see items that are going to be used for years and years and that are difficult to edit to have typos in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. From Access' point of view, linked tables and views are almost identical.

Except when linking a view, you need to tell Access the **primary key** - for tables it it determined automatically. Without specifying the PK, the linked view is read-only.

The Linked Tables Manager in Access shows only tables/views that are already linked.

To automate the process, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316883/3820271

Comment: The user trying to link the view may have no permissions for it, or there is another error, but Views can definitely be linked in Access. Many people do this all the time. @KarlHoaglund

Comment: Sorry Andre.  I think I had the name of my view wrong.