# Updated view in SQL - did not automatically update in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Do I need to relink or update an ODBC connection if I update a SQL view that is used in a query in Access?

Steps to reproduce

Update view in SQL > Save > open query that uses view in Access > no change

Comment: This may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316883/3820271

Answer (score 2):

If the change (to the view) involves changes to the structure (columns: names, numbers, data types, primary key, any unique indices) then you need to re-link in MsAccess (so that it reads those changes and saves them). If the change is only about the tables joined (FROM clause), or the selection criteria (WHERE, HAVING), aggregation (GROUP BY) etc, no need to re-link.